# Installing CMake command line tools on a Mac

Tags: macos, terminal, cmake

I installed CMake literally two days ago with no problems through the GUI and selecting "Install Command Line Tools". I just got a brand new Macbook and trying to install CMake again but the option has changed to "How to Install Command Line Tools" and just crashes the app when clicked

Is there a reason it has changed? Is there another way to install the command line tools?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

As of version 3.9.4, the "How to Install Command Line Tools" says:

> One may add CMake to the PATH:
>
> `PATH="/Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin":"$PATH"`
>
> Or, to install symlinks to '/usr/local/bin', run:
>
> `sudo "/Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake-gui" --install`
>
> Or, to install symlinks to another directory, run:
>
> `sudo "/Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake-gui" --install=/path/to/bin`

The middle option worked perfectly for what I needed: installing an older version of Swift using [swiftenv](https://github.com/kylef/swiftenv/blob/master/docs/building-swift.md).

Comment: As of version 3.20 this still works. Search in "Help" tab for 'Command line' and it will pop up. The middle version worked for me too.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like CMake 3.3.0 is broken in that respect...

Anyone finding themselves in the same situation should do what I've just done and revert to 3.2.3 and then the "Install Command Line Tools" is back in business

Answer (score 0):

First variant of the first comment works till the reboot of console.
So, I found solution to open path file

```bash
sudo nano /etc/paths
```

and after that wrote the next line:

```
"/Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin":"$PATH"
```

after that i can use `cmake` from the console

Comment: Yes. You alternatively can add the path statement to your .profile/.zprofile or .bashrc/.zshrc files. In bash, you'll need to type `EXPORT` before the `PATH=...`. That's not needed in zsh. See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26059/15074) at Unix & Linux Stack Exchange's *How to correctly add a path to PATH?* for additional details.

Comment: @leanne 
In the topic you sent there it thought that we ought not to use export to avoid duplication of path imports

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem today after updating to Sonoma 14 on a M1 chip. The easiest way I found of solving this issue was through [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) by following [these instructions](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/cmake#default);

**To install the command line tools run:** `brew install cmake`

**To install the man pages run** `brew install cmake-docs`

Though simple, this solution might be a little inconvenient for some people because the repository is not up-to-date, otherwise, it works just fine for me.